# Ruby Nokogiri text search not working with br tags and others

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using the Nokogiri gem in Ruby and running into some problems.

I want to scrape addresses from webpages and there is no set format to the way the addresses will be displayed.

I've got a list of postcodes and I want my Ruby script to return the node including the postcode so that I can find the rest of the address.

This is what I've got in Ruby, with some example HTML content:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

content1 = '
<div>
    <div>
        <div>Our Address:</div>
        1 North Street
        North Town
        North County
        N21 4DD
    </div>
</div>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(content1)
result = doc.search "[text()*='N21 4DD']"
puts result.inspect
```

This returns `[]`

I understand the example above is a strange way for an address to appear in HTML but it's the simplest way I can show the problems I've had. Here's another `content` variable that returns nothing:

```
content1 = '
<div>
    <div>Our Address:</div>
    <div>
        1 North Street<br>
        North Town<br>
        North County<br>
        N21 4DD
    </div>
</div>'
```

I know that Nokogiri might have trouble with the above because the `<br>` tags should be `</br>` but this is quite common on websites.

THIS EXAMPLE WORKS:

```
content1 = '
<div>
    <div>Our Address:</div>
    <div>
        1 North Street
        North Town
        North County
        N21 4DD
    </div>
</div>'
```

Can someone explain why the node is not being found from the first two `content` examples above and how I can fix this?

I'm not looking for a custom solution that will find the postcode in the sample `content` examples above – these are just for demonstration purposes. The postcode (and address) could be anywhere in the html – `body`, `p`, `div`, `td`, `span`, `li` etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Xpath:

`doc.xpath('.//div[contains(.,"N21 4DD")]')`

This still returns two nodes because there is a nested div. I'm not sure that there is a way to get the middle div without the 'Our Address' div because it is in the same node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the text won't necessarily be in a `div`. It may be in a `p`, `td`, just `body` etc. Also, for the second example `content` variable this solution returns all contents of the parent div including `<div>Our Address</div>`. Instead of the address div alone.

Comment: Thanks, I think it was returning the first because my answer was originally just contains("dd") which matches aDDress. See my updated answer, you don't actually have to specify the tag with `.at`

Comment: Thanks but I altered that before I ran it, so that wasn't the cause. `doc.at('*:contains("N21 4DD")')` returns the whole HTML node. Please try it yourself, maybe it's my Nokogiri install but it's just a standard Ruby bundler install so I would be surprised.

Comment: You are totally right. I updated it again to use xpath, but I think its a problem of the HTML design not of nokogiri. I would argue that this should be avoided with div classes or enforcing <p> tags... If you just have divs inside of divs with no way to distinguish which is which you will get the entire div back that matches.

Comment: I don't control the HTML – it's any webpage online, so I can't use classes or enforce <p> tags. My biggest frustration here is that my original code works perfectly (`doc.search "[text()*='N21 4DD']"`) as long as the HTML is valid. It doesn't work if there are any html quirks e.g. `br` tags. Maybe the solution lies in editing the HTML somehow.

Comment: Also, I don't think the xpath solution is any better. It's returning the first DIV it finds, so if the address div is nested five levels deep, it would return the DIV at the first level. Which isn't much more help than the `doc.at('*:contains("N21 4DD")')` option which returns the whole HTML node. Thanks for your efforts on this though.

Comment: That is the way it should work. Both divs have the text... and there is nothing unique to distinguish one from the other, if there can be any level of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the first one and how Nokogiri translates your "css" (that's not valid css btw):

```
Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for "[text()*='N21 4DD']"
#=> ["//*[contains(child::text(), 'N21 4DD')]"]
```

Ok, so here the problem is the child::text() will actually only match the first text node, which is the empty text before the "Our Address" div.

```
doc.search("//*[contains(child::text(), 'N21 4DD')]").length
#=> 0
```

No matches = not good.

Now let's try it jquery-style using the `:contains` pseudo:

```
Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for ":contains('N21 4DD')"
#=> ["//*[contains(., 'N21 4DD')]"]
doc.search("//*[contains(., 'N21 4DD')]").length
#=> 4
```

This is actually correct, but maybe not what you expected.

Let's try it one more way:

```
doc.search("//*[text()[contains(., 'N21 4DD')]]").length
#=> 1
```

It sounds like this is what you're looking for. Just the div that has the string in a child text node.